# Different Bluetooth Version on Linux and Windows

Tags: linux, windows, bluetooth

I have RTL8822BE PCI-E NIC with Bluetooth, on Windows Bluetooth version shows as 5.0 but on Linux shows as 4.2.
Why?
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

With generic driver:

[image]

On Linux:
[image]

Comment: According to Realtek page - https://www.realtek.com/en/products/communications-network-ics/item/rtl8822be - it has `integrated Bluetooth 2.1/3.0/4.2 USB interface controller`... not sure why Windows might detect it as being 5.0 ... driver issue?

Comment: Check HCI/LMP version.

Comment: Have you installed the Windows Bluetooth yourself? And where did you get it?

Comment: I have attached Some pictures from Windows and linux.

Comment: Note: with generic driver, it detects as Bluetooth 4.1(LMP7)

Comment: Note2:On Linux detected as Bluetooth 4.2!! What the Heck?